# I'm trying to display an image in Python 3.7.0 using Jupyter Notebook. Why isn't it working?

Tags: python, python-3.x, jupyter-notebook, jupyter

The image is called "pythontest.png". I'm trying to display the image using the following code:

```
from IPython.display import Image
img = 'pythontest.png'
Image(url=img)
print(Image)
```

but when I run the program it simply displays:

```
<class 'IPython.core.display.Image'>
```

What does that mean and how do I make it display the actual image? Thanks.

Comment: See I just tried that but it still displays     <class 'IPython.core.display.Image'>. Any other suggestions?

Comment: Try to remove the line `print(Image)`. `Image(url=img)` should handle the display in a notebook. (and Notebooks only show last value by default).

Comment: @S.Naj If you want to show it inside of a loop or something use `image_instance = Image(url=img)
display(image_instance)`

Comment: Still not working. Not sure why.

Answer (score 2):

There is an alternative of using `Matplotlib`

*`Matplotlib` is a plotting library for the Python programming language and its numerical mathematics extension NumPy*

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt #for showing the image
import matplotlib.image as mpimg #for reading the image
import numpy as np #just to be safe...lol
%matplotlib inline
#the above is a magic function to have images show in your notebook

image = mpimg.imread('pythontest.png') #loading/reading the image

plt.imshow(image) #displaying the image
```

Answer (score 1):

Let's say that the image is stored in pics folder. This Works for me:

```
from IPython.display import Image
import os

Image(filename=os.path('pics', 'pythontest.png'))
```

Comment: That didn't work because it said "name 'os' is not defined'. I'm using Python 3.7.0 on a Mac. Any other suggestions?

Comment: Do not forget to import the module "os"

Answer (score 0):

Your print statement has printed the type class of your image.  To display the image in the Jupiter notebook, just change your original code to the following:

```
from IPython.display import Image
imgUrl = 'pythontest.png'            # setup path and filename
img = Image(url=imgUrl)              # create the image object
img                                  # display the image
```

This code works in my Python 3.7 setup. Not sure about compatibility with other versions.